# How can i apply join in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

**how can i write this query in laravel 5.2**

```
SELECT institutes.id,institutes.country,degrees.institute_id,degrees.course     
FROM institutes INNER JOIN degrees 
ON  institutes.id=degrees.institute_id 
WHERE degrees.course ='master' AND institutes.country='america'
```

**Institute model**

```
protected $table = 'institutes';

protected $fillable = [
    'user_id','email', 'contact', 'country','about','name','city'

];


public function degree()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Degree','institute_id');

}
```

**degree model**

```
protected $table = 'degrees';

protected $fillable = [
    'institute_id','description', 'course', 'fees','session','education_req'

];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a following way

```
$data = Institute::join('degrees','institute.id','=','degrees.institute_id')
->select('table_name.column_name')
->get();
```

Comment: using join is ok, but you have to use relationships
e.g one institute have many degrees (One to Many Relationship)

Read From here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships